# fit exponential to a bivariate plot

Tags: r, distribution

I am using the cars data set (from ggplot2) and plotted the columns speed against dist in a scatterplot. Now I would like to fit different models for the distribution of the scatterplot (like exponential). I found a variety of ways to check how a data row (univariate) is distributed to a certain distribution (qqplot or also the fitdistr in MASS) but I don't know how to use these functions for the scatterplot or in the case of investigating the correlation of two variables.

Comment: Are you looking for regression tools like `lm` and `nls` ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- cars
fit <- nls(speed ~ a * (1-exp(b*dist)),cars,start=c(a=1,b=.01),algorithm="port")
df$speed.pred <- predict(fit)
ggplot(df, aes(x=dist))+
  geom_point(aes(y=speed))+
  geom_line(aes(y=speed.pred),linetype=2, colour="blue")
```

Note that this formulation treats `dist` as a predictor with 0 error. In other words, we assume `speed` has `error ~ N[0,sigma]`, but that `dist` has no error. If you assume that both `speed` and `dist` have error this is a [much more complicated problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) and the usual OLS techniques do not apply.